Installing a new M.2 SSD prevents booting to original windows on a SATA drive
My PC current uses a SATA SSD (Kingston), and has a few SATA HDDs in there too. My friend's laptop died and I'm trying to help recover the files. I pulled out the M.2 SSD from it and installed it into my PC, but now I can't get into my Windows - only my friends'.
But let me backup a bit: Originally, the boot order in my UEFI BIOS was "Windows Boot Manager" first, then the Kingston SSD and various other disks. If I try to boot directly to Kingston, it fails with "Disk Read Error" message as if windows wasn't installed - or rather, it seems unable to read the EFI partition on that disk. But everything worked fine using the "Windows Boot Manager" entry.
Now, upon installing the new M.2 SSD, a new entry appeared in UEFI BIOS called "Windows Boot Manager (M2: some-Model-Number)", though "Windows Boot Manager" still appears at the top. However, BOTH of these entries now result in booting the new M.2 drive, which I don't want to do (because it would require my friend to log in to their instance of Windows). But despite hours of web research, I can't find a simple way to get the "Windows Boot Manager" to target my Kingston drive when the M.2 is installed.
I'm also uncertain how to repair the boot partition on the Kingston so that I can choose it directly, rather than relying on the Windows Boot Manager. So, help with either problem would be appreciated.
Though I doubt it makes much difference, my motherboard is an Asus Prime z270-a. And, though the "other disks" are irrelevant to the issue, I should mention that one of them did come from an old PC and its EFI partition still works properly (I can select it from the boot menu and it'll load Windows, even with the M.2 installed).

This is expected.  You have introduced two system disks with EFI partitions, more than likely.  Windows Boot Manager is the correct EFI entry.  It would be best if you used that. Seems like a simply fix is to uninstall the disk and boot back into your disk.  Youll want to change the boot order also.

Actually I introduced a third, as I mentioned in my question, there is also an old drive with an EFI partition that does directly boot successfully, even with m.2 installed. Removing my friend's drive does of course restore my access to my new Windows on the Kingston drive, but that doesn't help my get the files off the m.2 drive for my friend. I need to either fix the WBM so it won't override with the m.2, or better yet, fix the Kingston drive so I can choose it manually to boot to, just like I can with the old drive.

Honestly, it sounds like a bug in your UEFI firmware.
I've seen firmware that stores only one "Windows Boot Manager" entry regardless of whether the two ESPs are on different drives, in which case the original entry can be replaced by a new entry.
It sounds like in your case even though your firmware seems to support multiple "WBM entries", yet the truth/result is they end up leading to the same ESP/WBM, which is NOT something normal/expected.
Theoretically it shouldn't have done any damage to your own ESP / installation, so instead of trying to repair it, you should just see if unplugging your friend's drive helps. (And you may even want to try booting without any system drives once, and then try again with only your own drive getting back in.)
If for example your UEFI firmware does not show any "WBM entry" with only your own drive installed, you may need to clear the data on the UEFI NVRAM as much as you can (like booting a "live" Linux drive in UEFI mode and removing anything removable under /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/ after removing their immutable flags with chattr -i; maybe with the battery removed for a minute or so in addition after shutting down from that). Less aggressive approach would be messing with the boot entries through efibootmgr. (WARNING: throughout history there had been claims that either of these manipulation could result in "bricking" the UEFI firmware. Personally I had no such experience with proper PC that the UEFI firmware / NVRAM data isn't on some eMMC or so, but NO WARRANTY FROM ME.) (It could take a somewhat longer time for some firmware to "recover" from such "reset" though, like 15s or so.)
You may also instead mount the ESP on Linux and remove /mountpoint/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi, given that there is a /mountpoint/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi that is actually identical to the former. Use cmp or a hash program like sha256sum to confirm that. That would "force" your UEFI firmware to look at a different path for "the same file" that would lead to the same result -- getting your installation booted. (You should see a new entry like UEFI: Kingston showing up then.)
P.S. The answer is written with the assumption that your friends Windows installation wasn't like a clone from your own. (But even if it were, I am still not seeing how the ESP on your drive could be messed up by it.)

Removing my friend's M.2 does put everything back how it was: One entry of "Windows Boot Manager" which loads Windows off the Kingston drive. However, it still fails if I manually choose to boot to the Kingston drive. I can manually boot to an old drive with Windows though, and can do so even with the m.2 installed. If I can't fix the WBM issue or the Kingston direct not problem, I might use that old windows to backup my friend's files to an external drive or cloud. Your answer doesn't really help me fix either issue, as I don't really understand how Linux will help here.

@Elbyron Well, I never intended to give you a "perfect fix" anyway, since it's quite obvious that there's something wrong with your UEFI firmware, which I cannot fix (and maybe no one can either). A significant portion of the answer was written just in case removing your friend's drive does not even put everything back how it was. Linux was mentioned because it offers interfaces / utilities that allows you to "mess with" the UEFI boot entries / data in the NVRAM (maybe Windows more or less does too, idk).

@Elbyron And as mentioned in the answer, one potential way to "achieve what you need" is to remove the file on your own installation that makes the firmware "auto-registers" a WBM entry (EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi under the ESP's root). This should make/force your firmware to offer you a "disk entry" (as long as a copy of the file is at EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi). The "disk entry" you have been seeing was probably a "legacy boot" entry that appears because you have enabled CSM (which is normal to "fail" for a UEFI Windows/WBM instllation).
